# Pybind11: Overloaded method without parameter

Tags: c++, pybind11

In my cpp class `CameraBase` I have 2 overloaded methods `getImageBuffer`

```
 class CameraBase {
        virtual CameraFrameErr getImageBuffer(unsigned char* const ext_buffer, const uint32_t buffer_size) = 0;
    
        virtual std::shared_ptr<ImageBufferBase> getImageBuffer();
    }
```

I wrapped the return types and followed [the documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html) and have the following binding:

```
py::class_<CameraBase, std::shared_ptr<CameraBase>, PyCameraBase>(m, "CameraBase")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("getImageBuffer", static_cast<CameraFrameErr (CameraBase::*)(unsigned char* const, const uint32_t)>(&CameraBase::getImageBuffer) )
        .def("getImageBuffer", static_cast<std::shared_ptr<ImageBufferBase>(CameraBase::*)()>(&CameraBase::getImageBuffer))
```

But when calling the method from Python3:

```
imageBuffer = np.array(cam.getImageBuffer(), copy = False)
```

I get

```
TypeError: getImageBuffer(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: _axcamera.LI_IMX490_GMSL2_SXProFrame, arg0: numpy.ndarray[uint8]) -> _axcamera.CameraFrameErr
    2. (self: _axcamera.LI_IMX490_GMSL2_SXProFrame, arg0: numpy.ndarray[uint16]) -> _axcamera.CameraFrameErr
    3. (self: _axcamera.LI_IMX490_GMSL2_SXProFrame, arg0: numpy.ndarray[int32]) -> _axcamera.CameraFrameErr
    4. (self: _axcamera.LI_IMX490_GMSL2_SXProFrame, arg0: numpy.ndarray[float32]) -> _axcamera.CameraFrameErr
    5. (self: _axcamera.LI_IMX490_GMSL2_SXProFrame, arg0: numpy.ndarray[float64]) -> _axcamera.CameraFrameErr
```